# How to set up common js/css files to be used by multiple projects

Tags: eclipse, war

I'm not in familiar territory, so if I say something unclear, please question me, or feel free to edit anything that needs editing.

I've been put on a GWT project, using Eclipse as our IDE.  My task was to make a JavaScript / jQuery user interface to replace the GWT one.  This UI would be used by other projects as well.  I've got the UI pretty well coded, but it will still be going through changes.  In the meantime, it's being used on three different projects, at least one of which is pure JS.

We've been copying all of my files (I have a lot of JS files, modularized and using require.js, as well as CSS and image files) in to each project.  For the GWT project, I've been copying the files into the war folder, while the JS project simply copies the files into the root level of their webpage.  This is a truly terrible way to do things - we don't have a primary source for the UI files, and each project is making separate changes.  We resolved this by checking the files in to our repository as a separate project.

The question is: What now?

I tried taking advantage of Eclipse's ability to create links and virtual folders.  It looks great in Project Explorer, but of course there's no actual file in the physical directory.  When I try running as a web application, these files aren't found.

Then I tried creating a project in Eclipse pointing to these files, and referring to it in the path for my require config.  This is higher than the application's root, though, so the files are unaccessable.

I can work on making require.js build all my js files together.  With enough effort, I can get all the images to go away by embedding them directly.  I was hoping to leave all of my css files, though - one of the features we're trying to show off is how easily we can change the theme of the UI this way, so I have a lot of the default jqueryui themes.  Of course, they won't change as frequently as my js code, so maybe it's not bad to copy them around.

I don't think I'm looking for something that impossible.  I know this boils down to knowing how to set up a web project properly.  Isn't there some way I can keep these files only in one place, yet have them be used by multiple web projects?

If it matters, I know we do have build scripts for these projects, but I haven't encountered them yet.

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I wasn't really hoping for the tumbleweed badge (guess I typed too much), but now that I got it, I'll give the answers I found:

The answer was simple: a symbolic link, and changing the code to look in the newly linked directory.  In *nix-land, this is easy: `ln -s`.  I had to look it up for [Windows](http://www.windows7home.net/how-to-create-symbolic-link-in-windows-7/), but it basically comes down to `mklink /D`.  Simply making this link then refreshing Eclipse makes the file appear in the workspace.  Editing it changes it in its home location.  The only problem is remembering to update that location as well as its consuming one when checking in code.

After I sent out that solution to my coworkers, one suggested that we do it through the source control system, instead.  Since we're currently using Visual SourceSafe, I could've used the `Share` command.  (I remember from past projects that there's a way to do this in SVN, as well).  I didn't go with the SourceSafe solution, simply because I read somewhere that Sharing won't update new or deleted files.  If you add or delete any, you have to delete the share and remake it.  I'd rather just make a symbolic link.